# In `/usr/include/mach-o/loader.h`, what's the mach filetype `mh_dylib_stub` for?

Tags: linker, mach-o, mach

I'm reading `mach-o/loader.h` and noticed this file type and it's description:

```
#define MH_DYLIB_STUB   0x9     /* shared library stub for static */
                                /* linking only, no section contents */
```

This sounds almost like an import library for PE/COFF. Can anybody point me to something that talks about it?

Comment: The man page of `strip` lists an option to produce such files with the `-c` option, however in my tests that broke the input file to the point where other tools (like `otool` or `nm`) would no longer be able to operate on it. That coupled with the fact that Apple has shipped text-based stub files (`.tbd`) in their SDKs leads me to believe that this is an abandoned legacy feature/format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a link-time only special object file which contains no code, but does contain symbols (LC_SYMTAB, DYSYMTAB) so that the linker can use it. It has made a cameo appearance around Xcode 7 before Apple moved to the proprietary ".tbd" files (which are textual).

Source: MacOS/iOS Internals, 2nd Edition, Chapter 6.